# Hebrew not rendering in \section{} using polyglossia after using textenglish{}

Tags: polyglossia, hebrew, english

i have had this problem lately where the main language is heberw and the second is english that when i use the \textenglish{} command in polyglossia it deosn't allow hebrew in sections to render properly

for example heres the latex

```latex
% Compile using XeLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\newcommand{\HEBipsum}{לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר סוברט לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם סולגק. בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש. תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.}

\begin{document}

\section{אחד 1}
\HEBipsum

\section{שתיים 2}
\HEBipsum
\textenglish{english inline}
\HEBipsum

\section{שלוש 3}
\HEBipsum

\end{document}
```

and this is the pdf generated

[image]

do you see how the Hebrew doesn't render and even the numbers are turning back into English in the third section.

I compiled using Xelatex but using Lualatex yields the same problem.

- any fixes?

Comment: which version of polyglossia are you using?

Comment: im using the overleaf website, so im not sure.

Comment: but if i revert back to TeX Live version 2022 (not 2023) it seems to fix it, is there any way to use 2023  and still make it work?

Comment: looks ok here (with texlive 2023). Show your log-file.

Comment: which one of these?
output.aux
output.chktex
output.log
output.pdfxref
output.stderr
output.stdout
output.synctex.gz

Comment: and ive noticed for some reason this is a problem in the logs


{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
Missing character: There is no ש (U+05E9) in font [lmroman12-bold]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ל (U+05DC) in font [lmroman12-bold]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ו (U+05D5) in font [lmroman12-bold]:+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no ש (U+05E9) in font [lmroman12-bold]:+tlig;!
] (./output.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-06-30>
 ***********
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been reported at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/603 and been fixed in version `1.65`. Since overleaf use an old version of `polyglossia`, you can "apply" the patch yourself:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian]{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfontsf}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam CLM}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfonttt}[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}

\newcommand{\HEBipsum}{לורם איפסום דולור סיט אמט, קונסקטורר אדיפיסינג אלית גולר מונפרר סוברט לורם שבצק יהול, לכנוץ בעריר גק ליץ, ושבעגט ליבם סולגק. בראיט ולחת צורק מונחף, בגורמי מגמש. תרבנך וסתעד לכנו סתשם השמה - לתכי מורגם בורק? לתיג ישבעס.}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_set:Nn \__xpg_textlanguage:nnnn
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nTF {#3}
      {
        \msg_show:nnn { polyglossia } { languagenotloaded } {#2}
      }{
        % Store embedding language name
        \global\let\xpg@save@languagename\languagename
        \group_begin:
        \bool_set_true:N \__xpg_inline_lang
        \xpg@otherlanguage[#1]{#3}
        \csuse{date#3}
        % This is a hook for external packages which want to access variants
        % via babelname (such as biblatex)
        \cs_if_exist_use:c{date@bbl@\babelname}
        \polyglossia@lang@settextdirection:nn{#3}{#4}
        \group_end:
        % Reset the language's/script's font families if the embedding script is latin
        \str_if_eq:eeT{\prop_item:Ne{\polyglossia@langsetup}{\xpg@save@languagename/lcscript}}{latin}
        {\resetfontlatin}
        % In case a \<lang>font is defined, re-activate that
        \xpg@set@normalfont{\xpg@save@languagename}
    }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__xpg_textlanguage:nnnn {nnen}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{אחד 1}
\HEBipsum

\section{שתיים 2}
\HEBipsum
\textenglish{english inline}
\HEBipsum

\section{שלוש 3}
\HEBipsum

\end{document}
```